# Does adding [Serializable] to the class have any performance implications?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, performance, attributes, serializable

I need to add the [Serializable] attribute to a class that is extremely performance sensitive.

Will this attribute have any performance implications on the operation of the class?

Comment: Only as long as it takes to make an instance of the attribute. Why, what have you noticed?

Comment: I am just asking ahead of time, so that I don't have to create another solution, if this had any perf issues.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Instances of attribute classes are only created when they're first accessed. If you don't do any serialization on that particular class, the `SerializableAttribute()` constructor will never be called, hence it won't cause any performance issues.

Here's an interesting article about attribute constructors:
http://www.codingonthetrain.com/2008/10/attribute-constructors.html

Answer (score 9):

Attributes are a metadata annotations so they don't add weight to a class at runtime, unless they are interpreted by the runtime in a certain way that makes it treat the class differently.

[Serializable] is simply a marker attribute used as a convention to indicate that the class is serializable, it has no effect and the runtime does not treat the classes in any special way.